# Best way to store and fetch image bytes?

Tags: database, data-structures, storage, file-storage

I have a case in my startup where I need to fetch images in bytes as fast as possible.

At the moment I'm storing the images in **Azure Storage** then I fetch them on the run and cache them into my database as bytes. On future requests these bytes will be fetched from the database directly. Fetching the bytes from the database is much faster, however, overtime it accumulated and now my database storage is **80%** used.

My database is also on **Azure** and reserving more size will be expensive, so I'm looking into a better cheap way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you ever expire the cache?

Comment: @candied_orange every 30 days or on certain events.

Comment: Consider tuning that. Is client side caching viable?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: "I need to fetch images in bytes as fast as possible." is essentially incompatible with "I'm looking into a better cheap way to achieve this." Decide whether cheap or fast is more important to you.

Comment: @PhilipKendall both are important. It's too early to say it's not possible

Comment: Decide whether it is _more important_ to you right now to reduce the time to serve images or to reduce your cost. One of the crucial skills in any business is the ability to prioritise - if you can't/refuse to do that, you will fail.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Again, **too early** for that decision. I understand your point but I haven't finished researching whether there's a way and I'm not in a rush.

Comment: First off, what kind of DB are we talking about?  How are you accessing and retrieving the binary data?  How are these images used i.e., are you presenting them to a client or are you processing them internally?

Comment: @JimmyJames db is Mysql, string bytes of those images are stored in the db as "longblob" after fetching them from db I'm including them into an apple wallet pass package file `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` which requires images as string bytes

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-performance-tiers#premium-performance) the premium tier is on SSD and optimized for low-latency.  Are you using the premium performance tier? I would be very surprised that a non-relational feature of a relational DB beats a system designed specifically for this purpose.  That would seem like a Azure Storage fail. Are you pulling these using async IO?  When we talk about speed, there's latency and throughput.  What do you mean by 'faster' here exactly?

Comment: Every 30 days sounds like a number plucked out of thin air. Do you have any usage data that would let you predict the impact of adjusting this number?

Comment: Also, what file format are you using for these images?

Comment: @candied_orange png

Comment: png can be done at wildly different compressions. Have you looked into improving your compression? Also still wondering about usage data.

Comment: @candied_orange maximum file size is around 30kb

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm actually using standard but even downloading them from cdn was slower than db

Comment: @Faisal When you say "downloading them" I take it you mean we are talking about throughput.  How many images are you pulling down at a time?

Comment: @JimmyJames 4 per request here is what I'm doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599686/image-to-byte-array-from-a-url

Comment: @Faisal The accepted solution there is not what is shown in the current MS docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#download-blobs

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852997/best-way-to-store-and-fetch-image-bytes "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Have you looked into having links direct to the Azure blob storage to let Azure's infrastructure take care of the parallelism you need?  I do challenge your assertion that the database is going to be faster than just using Azure blob storage directly, or a Redis cache.

Comment: @gnat Apologies, just didn't know what's the place for my question

Comment: @JimmyJames The one in the MS docs shows downloading the blob into a local file in my application server; meaning that I'll have to download it then convert it to string bytes then use it then removing the downloaded blob. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Can you elaborate on what do you mean by direct links to Azure?

Comment: You should be able to get a URL to directly download any blob.  I work with AWS, but the offerings are similar.  Read the Azure documentation.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch @JimmyJames @candied_orange Fetching the blob directly from Azure was actually faster using `DownloadToByteArray`. I was doing it wrong by downloading image bytes using the public http link of the image. Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

There's two issues in your problem statement:

1. A cache is a subset of the larger data to server files that are accessed more frequently.  **You have to invalidate low hit rate cache entries** or you will consume all your resources.
2. Azure Blob storage is designed to serve up your blob's bytes over HTTPS with high speed, reliability, and scalability.

By copying your blobs into your database, you are simply duplicating data.  I highly doubt serving from the database is faster than having Azure blob storage serve the data for you.  While databases can store binary data, that's not really their main use, so it is rarely optimized as storage mediums designed from the ground up for that purpose.

I highly recommend that you examine the ways that you have designed your application to find where it is causing bottlenecks.  If you need to have your application as a proxy to the data, make sure of the following:

- Do not read the whole blob as an array of bytes--it wastes memory and can cause massive garbage collections
- Make sure you stream the bytes from the blob storage stream to the response stream
- Design around passing single use URLs (Azure storage can do this), and let the browser pull the data directly
- Look at the differences in how you are handling binary data in the database to how you are handling it in blob storage.  Your algorithm may need to be optimized

In short, make sure you understand what makes Azure storage "slow".  If you are testing locally on your machine and your test database is local on your machine, you are artificially penalizing Azure storage.

Granted, I come from an AWS background, and AWS S3 is much faster than serving binaries from an RDS database--particularly at scale.  Microsoft is also a smart company, I'm sure the Azure storage is at least close to S3 in performance and scalability.